# How can i implement ambient Occlusion (SSAO) for Horde3d?

Tags: ssao, horde3d

i've read couple of blog posts about the ssao effect but so far but i dont' know where to begin im beginner on the whole thing of GPU programming. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://kuko.serveblog.net/2012/05/08/horde3d-ssao-effect-ambient-occlusion-tutorial/

Comment: dead link walking...